# how to get particular column value from DataGrid and add it as combobox items in wpf using Linq to sql concept

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

[image: State]

I have loaded the above table state in DataGrid control.But i want to get  the particular column **state_name** and then add it's value(Tx,TN,UP,Nul,.....) to the combobox items. The belove code what i wrote to load the state table into DataGrid Control.

```
 using (DataClasses1DataContext _mc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var _MyCountry = from cntry in _mc.GetTable<state>() select cntry;
            grd_table.ItemsSource = _MyCountry;                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this but I would personally use linQ because of how easy it is to use. I guess you want the value of your ComboBoxItems to be the state_id of the state and the displayed name state_name?
Does the following code help you?

```
        grd_table.ItemsSource = _MyCountry;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = (from m in _MyCountry select m).ToList();
        comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "state_name";
        comboBox.SelectedValuePath = "state_id";
```